# What is the difference between these 2 ways of exporting from a Javascript module?

Tags: javascript, module

I'm new to JS modules and am confused by the following:

#### Declaring `y` explicitly & returning it will export it:

```
// Outputs "hello"
(function (x) {
    var y = x;
    return y;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "y is not defined"
console.log(y);
```

#### Declaring `y` explicitly & *not* returning it does not export it:

```
// Outputs "undefined"
(function (x) {
    var y = x;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "y is not defined"
console.log(y);
```

#### Declaring `y` implicitly & *not* returning it *will* put it in the global scope?

```
// Outputs "undefined"
(function (x) {
    y = x;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "hello"
console.log(y);
```

I understand what's happening in the first 2 examples, but what is the third case doing, and why?

Comment: those aren't really modules...

Comment: @dandavis I know, but that is the basic "building block" syntax of modules, correct?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the output will be `hello` since `y` is declared without `var` or `let`, So `y` will be in global(window) scope

```js
// Outputs "undefined"
(function(x) {
  y = x;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "hello"
console.log(y);
```

In this case `y` is declared with `var` keyword so the scope of the variable `y` is inside the function and cannot be accessible outside the function. So it will throw `ReferenceError: y is not defined` .Note the term [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) which is thrown when  non-existent variable is referenced. In the below case you are trying to refer an variable outside its scope

```js
// Outputs "hello"
(function(x) {
  var y = x;
  return y;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "y is not defined"
console.log(y);
```

But if you assign the iife to a variable you can get the return value

```js
let k = (function(x) {
  var y = x;
  return y;
}('hello'));

// Outputs "y is not defined"
console.log(k);
```

Comment: I'm still confused as to how `y` gets into the global scope when it's declared inside the function expression. I thought that "scoped" the variables to that method only?